# Getting Uri of image returns null on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, bitmap, uri, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to get the Uri of a bitmap from memory. I am doing it as this:

```
public static Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

This method is suggested most of the **stackoverflow** questions. It works fine on Nougat. But it crashes on Marshmallow. This is the error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.metronome.caloriemeter, PID: 14035
>                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
>                                                                                   at android.net.Uri$StringUri.(Uri.java:480)
>                                                                                   at android.net.Uri$StringUri.(Uri.java:470)
>                                                                                   at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:442)
>                                                                                   at com.metronome.caloriemeter.utils.BitmapUriProvider.getImageUri(BitmapUriProvider.java:21)
>                                                                                   at com.metronome.caloriemeter.fragments.SocialFragment.shareOnFacebook(SocialFragment.java:144)
>                                                                                   at com.metronome.caloriemeter.fragments.SocialFragment.access$000(SocialFragment.java:35)
>                                                                                   at com.metronome.caloriemeter.fragments.SocialFragment$1.onTouch(SocialFragment.java:85)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9371)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2255)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2255)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2255)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2255)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2255)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2255)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2255)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2255)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2410)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1744)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2805)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
>                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2371)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9597)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4234)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4100)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3699)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3665)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3791)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3673)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3848)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3699)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3665)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3673)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5926)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5900)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5861)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6029)
>                                                                                   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>                                                                                   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:331)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:218)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThr

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Or at least is there any other mthod to get the bitmap?

Comment: "This method is suggested most of the stackoverflow questions" -- none are from any Android experts, I hope. Your approach wastes heap space, and neither you nor your user have no control over where the image winds up. As a result, at best, you are cluttering up the user's storage, and at worst, you are saving an image in a public place, where the user would prefer that the image not be public. Or at least is there any other mthod to get the bitmap?" -- you already have the `Bitmap`. It is a parameter to your method. What *exactly* do you need this `Uri` for?

Comment: For example, if the `Uri` is for something like `ACTION_SEND` or `ACTION_VIEW`, `compress()` the `Bitmap` to a `FileOutputStream`, on a file located in `getCacheDir()`. Set up `FileProvider` to serve from the cache directory, and use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get the `Uri`. Now, you skip the intermediate in-memory JPEG and the image file is kept private. You can clean the cache every day or two.

Comment: First of all, I am deleting the image after I do what I want. So the users storage will be freed after this. Secondly, I am using a library called Shareble and it needs the uri of the image. So I have to get the uri of my bitmap which it is actually a view on layout. Meaning that, I am converting a view to a bitmap, then saving it, then getting the image's uri, then I am deleting it. I need to save the image to somewhere to get its uri. This is why I am doing this.

Comment: "I am deleting the image after I do what I want" -- you have no idea how long the other party needs the image. It may be done in a few seconds, or perhaps a bit longer. And, while it is out there, other apps can get to it. "I need to save the image to somewhere to get its uri" -- then follow the recipe from my previous comment, to save the image in a private location and use `FileProvider` to selectively grant access to the app that needs it.

Comment: Thank you I was searching your recipe last 5 minutes. I found something but it is not using getCacheDir(). If you provide some code I can accept it as the answer. Otherwise I have to search more.By the way, I want to delete it from cache after what I do with it, Is it possible too?